# Foundation 5 - exclude unnecessary components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

Is there a way to exclude foundation components in my rails project from being included in page requests? Every time I hit a page I get a list of requests even though these items are not used.

GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-28 10:40:50 +0200

GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-28 10:40:50 +0200

.

.

.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can turn off asset debugging inside development.rb
just set

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

and it will compile all foundation files inside one js :)
or you can stop using the foundation gem and manually add the required foundation files inside your app

Comment: Also, the [quiet_assets](https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets) gem will remove log messages while not merging all of the individual files into a single one which may make debugging more difficult.